# Probability that random variable is greather than a number

Tags: probability, statistics

I'm currently writing my bachelor's thesis in game theory but am no that great at probability. I have a problem where I know the distribution of a random variable call it $X$ (a bunch of binomials multiplied), but I need to find $P(X>K)$, $K\in R^+$.

I'm pretty sure there has to be some standard approach to this, but I can't figure it out myself. Specifically
$P(X=A)=a$, $P(X=B)=b$, $P(X=C)=c$, $P(X=D)=d$, $a+b+c+d=1$.

Essentially what I'm looking for is some way to find a closed form expression for $P(X>K)$ given arbitrary $A,B,C,D$.

Thanks in advance!

Edit: Actually another problem occurred to me: we have another level of complexity which i didnt notice at first. We have $A(y,z), a(y,z), B(y,z), b(y,z)$ etc; i.e. the probability that the variable is greater actually changes with the probability distribution of the variable itself. Moreover, they are not necesarily monotonic in the same direction, but they are monotonic in $y$ and $z$.

Comment: Pardon me, must have forgotten, will get right to it!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Let $S = \{x\in \{A,B,C,D\}\,|\,x>K\}$. Then $P(X>K)=\sum_{x\in S} P(X=x)$.

Put less formally, to find the probability of $X>K$, you just add the probabilities that $X$ is equal to numbers greater than $K$. (Example: if you are flipping ten coins, the probability of getting more than seven heads is the probability of eight heads plus the probability of nine heads plus the probability of 10 heads.) This works as long as $X$ only takes on finitely many values (which in your example it does).

Comment: Thanks, that expression may be useful. However, I probably should have said that I understand that part. The problem is that I don't in advance know what K is. In my model it is player strength relation, which can be arbitrarily large. 

Anyway, as I said, you putting it in a bit more set-theoretically might help, as I'm more familiar with those branches of math.

Thanks again!

Answer (score 1):

$$P(X>K)=a\hbox{$1\!\rm I$}_{K<A}+b\hbox{$1\!\rm I$}_{K<B}+c\hbox{$1\!\rm I$}_{K<C}+d\hbox{$1\!\rm I$}_{K<D}$$
Where $\hbox{$1\!\rm I$}_{K>E}$ indicates $1$ if $K<E$ and $0$ elsewhere.